# Basic multiboot USB guide

Tags: boot, usb, bootloader

There are some Question here on askubuntu about this. but they mostly use GUI, and or cli.

What am looking for is, a basic guide on how to install `grub` or other on my `16GB` USB, and a simple guide on how to edit a `bootmenu`? so that i can add my `xp.iso`, for know i only need it to boot from xp, latter on, other operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

The multiboot solution [Easy2Boot](http://www.easy2boot.com) is based on grub4dos and you can make an E2B USB drive from linux.
Just make an E2B USB drive and simply copy over your XP ISO file to the \_ISO\WINDOWS\XP folder.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to use this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: this is the easiest solution , it include even the Sata drivers needed for XP

Answer (score 1):

There are some links that describe how to use 'grub-n-iso' systems. Some of them indicate how to edit the configuration files. I think the following links and links from them can help you,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2), overview with links, e.g. [.../Grub2/ISOBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot)

[When booting from a live USB, graphics error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935300/when-booting-from-a-live-usb-graphics-error/935345#935345), scroll down to Multiboot ...

[wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive), contains detailed editing tips and links

[MultiBoot with Multiple Persistent partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850319/multiboot-with-multiple-persistent-partitions)

---

I don't use multiboot USB drives. I find them difficult to keep up to date. Instead I store and update the live operating systems and installers as iso files in my main computer and  create a boot drive from an iso file, when I need it. My USB pendrives are 'temporary devices'.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try yumi? IMHO it`s the best tool to manage multiboot USB, by the way very easy too. [You can find it here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) . I have tried only under windows, but you can install it on ubuntu as well.

Comment: doesn't seem to work under Ubuntu? but i am searching for a minimalistic solution as possible

Comment: Did you download version for ubuntu? On this site you can find other software to made multiboot, don`t be lazy, look more carefully ;)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to use this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)