# Installation from USB (Displayport, 1440 resolution)

Tags: boot, nvidia, display-resolution, displayport

I hope you can help me out. I have some experience with Ubuntu using it for +5 years now at work and home. But if the initial installation steps fail, I am screwed.

Ubuntu starts from USB stick into GRUB, where I select the live OS. But then, after a few seconds, it just shows an all black screen when connected to displayport, or all pink screen when HDMI. That's all.

I tried Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and Mint 18.2.

My PC specs:

- Ryzen 1600X
- Gigabyte GA-AB350 Gaming 3
- G.Skill FlareX DDR4-3200 16GB
- Samsung 960 Evo 500GB M.2
- MSI GeForce GTX 970 GAMING 4G
- Dell S2716D (Displayport 1.2a, 2560 x 1440, 144Hz, G-sync)

It might be because of the high resolution, or displayport? Or do I need special BIOS settings?

I tried booting the USB stick on my notebook. That works.

Finally, I want a dual boot system with Windows 10.

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried with the boot option `nomodeset`? See these links (and links from them) for more details, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/935300/when-booting-from-a-live-usb-graphics-error/935345#935345

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I will try it later this evening.